# Libgdx how to create new objects of body to draw dynimcally

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to make a game where apples will fall from sky and allow boy to eat them
I had already made the environment and the boy and one apple falling correctly
but I want to make more objects of the apple to fall from sky at specific time
how can I repeat the calling of apple class, where I have to call it 
I built the apple body inside the apple class and use it inside the PlayScreen class and this is the code:
Apple class:

```
public class Apple extends Sprite {

    public PlayScreen screen;
    public World world;
    public Apple apple;
    public Body b2body;
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public float counter;
    private TextureRegion Apple;
    //private Animation collectorRu;
    private float stateTimer;
    private boolean toDestroy;
    private boolean destroyed;
    public Apple(World world,PlayScreen screen)
    {
        super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("boys3"));
        this.screen=screen;
        this.world=world;
        stateTimer=0;
        defineApple();
        Apple=new TextureRegion(getTexture(),0,0,120,120);
        setBounds(0, 0, 20 / Fruits.PPM, 20 / Fruits.PPM);//here we can change the size of our Animation
        setRegion(Apple);
        toDestroy=false;
        destroyed=false;
        velocity=new Vector2(0,-2);
        counter=0;
    }
    public void defineApple() {
        BodyDef bdef=new BodyDef();

        bdef.position.set(100/Fruits.PPM,200/Fruits.PPM);
        bdef.type=BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        b2body=world.createBody(bdef);
        FixtureDef fdef=new FixtureDef();
        //PolygonShape shape=new PolygonShape();
        CircleShape shape=new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(7 / Fruits.PPM);
        fdef.filter.categoryBits=Fruits.APPLE_BIT;
        fdef.filter.maskBits=Fruits.GROUND_BIT | Fruits.COLLECTOR_BIT;
        fdef.shape=shape;
        b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);

    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {

        stateTimer += dt;
        if(toDestroy&&!destroyed)
        {
            world.destroyBody(b2body);
            destroyed=true;
            stateTimer=0;
        }
        if(!destroyed) {
            b2body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
            setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
        }


    }
    public void draw(Batch batch)
    {
        if(!destroyed )
        {
            super.draw(batch);
        }
    }
    public void hit()
    {
        toDestroy=true;

    }

}
```

the Playscreen class:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private Fruits game;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gameport;
    private Hud hud;
    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    private Collector player;
    private boolean right=true;
    private boolean left=true;
    private Apple apple;
    public float counter;

    private Controller controller;


    public PlayScreen(Fruits game)
    {
        this.game=game;
        gamecam=new OrthographicCamera();
        gameport=new FitViewport(Fruits.V_WIDTH/Fruits.PPM,Fruits.V_HIEGT/Fruits.PPM,gamecam);
        hud=new Hud(game.batch);
        atlas=new TextureAtlas("mypack.pack");
        mapLoader=new TmxMapLoader();
        map=mapLoader.load("level3.tmx");
        renderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,1/Fruits.PPM);
        gamecam.position.set(gameport.getWorldWidth()/2,gameport.getWorldHeight()/2f,0);

        world=new World(new Vector2(0,-10),true);
        b2dr=new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        new B2WorldCreator(this);
        player=new Collector(world,this);
        world.setContactListener(new WorldContactListener());
        controller=new Controller(game.batch);
        apple=new Apple(world,this);

        counter=0;

    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public TextureAtlas getAtlas()
    {
        return atlas;
    }
    public void handleinput(float dt)
    {
        if (controller.isRightPressed()&&player.b2body.getPosition().x<3.7f)
        {
            if(right)
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.3f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
            else {
                player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
                right=true;
                left=false;
            }
            //player.b2body.setTransform(player.b2body.getPosition().x+0.05f,player.b2body.getPosition().y,player.b2body.getAngle());
        }
        if (controller.isLeftPressed()&&player.b2body.getPosition().x>0.26f ) {
            if(left)
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.3f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);//5
            else {
                player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
                right=false;
                left=true;
            }
            //player.b2body.setTransform(player.b2body.getPosition().x - 0.05f, player.b2body.getPosition().y, player.b2body.getAngle());
        }
        if (controller.isUpPressed() && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0) {

            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

        }
    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {
        handleinput(dt);

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
        player.update(dt);
        apple.update(dt);

        gamecam.update();
        renderer.setView(gamecam);
    }
    public TiledMap getMap()//12 this is for Goomba
    {
        return map;
    }
    public World getWorld()
    {
        return world;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();
        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        //Gdx.app.log("hi","hello");
        counter+=delta;
        player.draw(game.batch);
        apple.draw(game.batch);

        game.batch.end();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();
        controller.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gameport.update(width,height);
        controller.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        b2dr.dispose();
        hud.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saleh, to queue up tasks (like spawning a new Apple), use `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer.schedule(Timer.Task task, float delaySeconds, float intervalSeconds)`.

Comment: thanks for helping but where do I have to use such task? is it inside Playscreen class at the render  or the update method or I have to make new method or inside apple class??

Comment: Use it once when the game starts. The task parameter is the spawning of the apple, intervalSeconds is how often the apple should spawn.